# Electric bill for reactive power

Tags: power, ac

I have read that if you don't unlug the charger from the socket after charging your phone, although it is not connected to the phone, it still consumes power and your electricity bill adds up.

On the other hand if I leave the charger plugged without the phone I assume the only power is reactive power and in residential buildings we don't get charged for reactive power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of factors to consider.

1) Old-style wall-wart chargers use a transformer that runs at line frequency (50 or 60 Hz). High-quality line-frequency transformers *do* present a large reactive load to the AC Mains.

Unfortunately, most wall-wart chargers do **NOT** use high-quality transformers. They usually run very close (or into) saturation and thus run warm or even hot. That heat shows up on your power bill as energy consumed.

2) Modern chargers use a switch-mode power supply. These can be extremely efficient when idling.

Bottom line is: If the charger is running warm, it is consuming energy and that usage will show up on your power bill.

Comment: Even though - they still use some non reactive power and your bill will add up, 0.5 W are 4 kWh per year or around 1€ in Germany, yeah it's not much, but everything counts. Well a good charger is probably more like 0.2 W, so more like 2 kWh, I should measure some chargers maybe...

Comment: I already did: [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186886/can-i-keep-my-charger-plugged-in/186902#186902), turned out they were around 0.1 W...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the transformer inside the charger is not ideal and has some winding resistance and therefore will consume a small amount of active power even if the phone is unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

Low cost chargers probably consume 0.5 W when idle (no load, no phone plugged in). High quality ones (e.g. Apple) consume < 100 mW -- typically 10 mW -- when idle.